# Number counting to find subsets frequency

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to find the combination of numbers which frequently occur in N number of sets (same size, no duplicates within one set).

For ex:

```
{3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 11}
{3, 7, 2, 11, 5, 14}
{8, 2, 1, 11, 14, 6}
{9, 1, 12, 8, 17, 4}
{4, 10, 16, 5, 14, 3}
```

I used a number counting algorithm for finding the occurences of individual numbers across the sets.

```
public static int[] Counting (int []A, int m )
{
    int n = A.Length;
    int[] count = new int[m+1];
    Array.Clear(count, 0, m+1);
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        count[A[k]] += 1;
    return count;
}
```

Is there an algorithm for doing the same with a subset. In the example above {2, 11}, {3,2, 11}, {11, 14} occur together more frequently. The output should have the count of a subset i.e. for the example above **{2, 11}** frequency is **3**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this work for you?

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>> getAllSubsets = null;
getAllSubsets = xs =>
    (xs == null || !xs.Any())
        ? Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<int>>()
        :  xs.Skip(1).Any()
            ? getAllSubsets(xs.Skip(1))
                .SelectMany(ys => new [] { ys, xs.Take(1).Concat(ys) })
            : new [] { Enumerable.Empty<int>(), xs.Take(1) };

var source = new int[][]
{
    new [] {3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 11},
    new [] {3, 7, 2, 11, 5, 14},
    new [] {8, 2, 1, 11, 14, 6},
    new [] {9, 1, 12, 8, 17, 4},
    new [] {4, 10, 16, 5, 14, 3},
};

var subsets = source.Select(x => getAllSubsets(x).Select(y => new { key = String.Join(",", y), values = y.ToArray() }).ToArray()).ToArray();

var keys = subsets.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.key)).Distinct().ToArray();

var query =
    from key in keys
    let count = subsets.Where(x => x.Select(y => y.key).Contains(key)).Count()
    where count > 1
    orderby count descending
    select new { key, count, };
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

The first result of `5` is for the empty set, which each set contains.

Comment: Nice, I was stumped at creating all permutation using linq.